# Using a string that corresponds to a participant ID and a score

Tags: python

My current code:

```
def checker(list1, minScore):
    for x in lst:
        print(x[1])

#code for the function here





myList1 = [ ['P12', 20], ['P11',2], ['P4',22],['P5',12],['P13',2]]

value = int(input("Enter the min score threshold: "))

res = checker(mylist1, value)

print("Participants with scores above the threshold include: ",res)





mylist2 = [ ['P2',5],['P113',22]]

value = int( input("Enter the min score threshold: "))

res = checker( mylist2, value)

print("participants with scores above threshold include: ", res)
```

I am unsure on how to incorporate that statement above into my code, any sort of direction or hints would really help with how to write the code missing in my code.

Comment: Incorporate "that" statement in what way — what statement and in what way?

Comment: Please put the sample run as text instead of a picture.

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you switch to dict instead of a list of list which is complex.

```
def checker(lst, minScore):
    return [key for key, value in lst.items() if value > minScore]


myList1 = {'P12': 20,
           'P11': 2,
           'P4': 22,
           'P5': 12,
           'P13': 2}

value = int(input("Enter the min score threshold: "))

res = checker(myList1, value)

print("Participants with scores above the threshold include: ", res)

# Output for threshold 6 =  ['P12', 'P4', 'P5']
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic you want to follow here is simple to understand. You want to create a new list containing the ID's (keep that in mind) of players with a score greater than a threshold. These are the two main informations.

Basic reminder :
To compare two values, use <, > or ==.
To add an *item* to a *list*, use *list*.append(*item*).
To build a for loop iterating through a list, say for *item* in *list*:

**I'm now going to start building the code, so don't look at it if you only want hints or directions.**

Let's iterate through a list first.

```py
def checker(lst, minScore):
    for couple in lst:
        # some code
```

Now, python will go through each and every *couple* contained in the list. But we want to check for the score, so let's add the if statement that we will go through if the score is above the threshold.

```py
def checker(lst, minScore):
    for couple in lst:
        if couple[1] > minScore:
            # add the id to the list
```

Note that I wrote couple[1] to get the score in the couple, since every item in the main list is itself a list made out of a string a an integer. For further advancement, we could use a dictionary to represent players and their score, or even a class. I'm including these at the very bottom of the answer.

Now, let's grab the ID of the player that meets the requirement.

```py
def checker(lst, minScore):
    for couple in lst:
        if couple[1] > minScore:
            id = couple[0] # This will use "P10" as an id, for example
            # id = couple[0][1:]  # This will use "10" as an id, for example
```

Now, let's create the list that we want to return and add every player meeting the condition. We can then return this list at the end of the method.

```py
def checker(lst, minScore):
    finalList = []
    for couple in lst:
        if couple[1] > minScore:
            id = couple[0]
            finalList.append(id)
    return finalList
```

We now have a method that returns a list containing the player IDs that have a score above the threshold. For example, for your first list and with a threshold of 15, it would return ["P12", "P4"].
Feel free to ask more questions if you want more help, I'd be glad to help you out.

The same code, using a class named Player to represent the players :

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, number, score):
        self.score = score
        self.number = number


def checker(lst, minScore):
    finalList = []
    for player in lst:
        if player.score > minScore:
            id = player.number
            finalList.append(id)
    return finalList


playerList = [Player(10, 12), Player(8, 32), Player(19, 4), Player(22, 16)]
print(checker(playerList, 15))
```

This is much more appropriate if you're planning onto giving each player more characteristics, such as its age, sex, position,...

If you only want to have an ID and a score, you can use dictionaries :

```py
playersDict = {
    "P10": 12,
    "P8": 32,
    "P19": 4,
    "P22": 16
}


def checker(dct, minScore):
    finalList = []
    for id in dct:
        if dct.get(id) > minScore:
            finalList.append(id)
    return finalList


print(checker(playersDict, 15))
```